# Sequence of text object yanks in vim mapping

Tags: vim

I would like to yank the inner contents of `<...>` *or* `(...)` expressions in a mapping.

While in normal mode I can type the two-yank sequence `yi<yi(`. One of the yanks will be empty and the other will match the desired contents. The net effect is to match the contents no matter they were inside `()` or `<>`.

Now if I put the same sequence in a map it seems to abort when the first yank fails, so it only matches the inner content for `<...>` expressions (because in my example `yi<` is the first probed yank).

Instead, if I put `:normal yi<<CR>:normal yi(<CR>`, the mapping works the same than when I manually type `yi<yi(` in normal mode. Moreover `:normal yi<yi(` also fails.

It seems to me that yanking a non-matched text object always ends with an error and aborts the current mapping or `:normal` execution. But I can't find that behavior explicitly documented in the vim docs. The `E` flag is not included in my `cpoptions`, although it's stated that it affects `y{motion}` not `y{object}`.

Can anyone clarify this weird behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the semantics of `:normal` changes when it is contained in a `try...catch` loop, or executed through `:silent!`: Without it, execution of the command sequence aborts when an error is encountered; the rest of the sequence is discarded (like in a macro). With it, all commands execute, even if an error occurs.

When you manually type those two yanks in succession, you're effectively ignoring the error.

#### solution

Therefore, you can get the desired behavior with

```
:silent! normal! yi<yi(
```

#### alternative

Another way would be to first clear the register, do the first yank, and only execute the second, alternative yank if the register is still empty.

Comment: Thanks Ingo, besides clarifying the point I find your suggestion a bit cleaner than calling `:normal` twice. Why is it that calling `:normal` twice also works? Doesn't `:normal` propagate the error the executed normal commands raised?

Comment: Calling `:normal` twice is exactly like typing interactively; you're discarding the error that happens after the first yank. There's no "propagation" because this is just a beep meaning "can't do that here".